# How is the input from a "read -r" statement stored in the provided variable?

Tags: shell-script

Just trying to understand what read -r is doing in the below script. Is this stored in an array format

```
FILENAME=$1

#============================================================
# Function: processOrgs()
#============================================================
function processOrgs() {
  # Write the header record to a new file
  echo "ORG,SPACE,APPS" > $FILENAME
  # Get the list of available orgs and process each individually
  cf orgs | grep -v "Getting orgs" | grep -v "^name$" | grep -v "^$" | \
  while read -r ORG; do \
    processOrg $ORG; \
  done
}
```

Comment: Just a note for improvement, the function call `processOrg` does not match the actual function, `processOrgs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read -r ORG` reads one line of output and stores it into a variable named `ORG`. Together with the `while` loop it will call processOrg for every line of output from the previous command `cf orgs | grep -v "Getting orgs" | grep -v "^name$" | grep -v "^$"`.

The `-r` flag is described in the manual page: do not allow backslashes to escape any characters.